# exclude html with regex and select only the text

Tags: html, regex

could you help me, I'm using a content extractor in regex but I have a problem extracting a subtitle:

```
<h2 class="page-title">Jesse Vega Schoolgirl <span class="duration">14 min</span> </h2>
```

I would like to select only the text and exclude the `<span class="duration">14 min</span>`

just stay like this

**Jesse Vega Schoolgirl** or so `<h2> Jesse Vega Schoolgirl </h2>`

I appreciate your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, since your text is html, that you are trying to use javascript. So, the following will do it quickly.

.*title\">([0-9a-zA-Z ]+).*

Result will be in group 1.

Example:

```
    let str = '<h2 class="page-title">Jesse Vega Schoolgirl <span class="duration">14 min</span> </h2>';
    let groups = str.match(/.*title\">([0-9a-zA-Z ]+).*/);
    alert(groups[1]);
```

Adding to the response, if there are more characters to match, you just need to add them to the group, as follows:
https://jsfiddle.net/fj2146ye/

Comment: If JavaScript can be used, you should better traverse the DOM.

Comment: thanks, it works partially but sometimes it doesn't take all the text when it has hyphens "-" or parentheses "()", for example: Jesse Vega - Schoolgirl

just choose : Jesse Vega

Any idea to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: @juan Of curse, my example was based on your text, but you can run it like /.*title\">([-_\(\)0-9a-zA-Z ]+).*/